# i want to use kendo grid in asp.net application i'm not able to find any source can anyone guide me

Tags: asp.net, json, ajax

I want to use kendo grid in asp.net application I'm not able to find any source can anyone guide me how to bind data to kendo grid using json data.

```
    function LoadDevices() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'AblCMS.aspx/GetPlayerList',
        type: 'POST',

        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",

        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            if (typeof (playerList) == 'object') {
                playerList.destroy();
            }
            playerList = $('#datatable-player-list').on('draw.dt', function () {


                $('#datatable-player-list tbody').off("click");
                $('#datatable-player-list tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {

                    if ($(this).hasClass('unchanged')) { alert('You cannot uncheck the player you are editing for.'); return false; };
                    if ($(this).hasClass('bg-success')) {
                        $(this).removeClass('bg-success');
                    } else {
                        var success = $(this).addClass('bg-success');

                    }
                });
            }).DataTable({
                "aaSorting": [0, 'desc'],
                "aaData": JSON.parse(result.d.PlayerList),
                "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {

                    if (aData["PlayerId"] == options.pkey) {
                        $(nRow).addClass('bg-success').addClass('unchanged');
                    }
                },
                "aoColumns":
                [
                    { "sWidth": "20%", "mData": "PlayerName", 'sType': 'string', "bVisible": true, "bSearchable": true },
                    { "sWidth": "10%", "mData": "Screen", 'sType': 'string', "bVisible": true, "bSearchable": true },
                    { "sWidth": "10%", "mData": "BranchName", 'sType': 'string', "bVisible": true, "bSearchable": true },
                    { "sWidth": "10%", "mData": "City", 'sType': 'string', "bVisible": true, "bSearchable": true },
                    { "sWidth": "10%", "mData": "BranchCode", 'sType': 'string', "bVisible": true, "bSearchable": true }
                ]
            });
        }
    });
    $('#modal-player-list').modal();
}
```

This is my code, I hope someone can help me very soon.